# __future__ import annotations not resolving circular import for type hinting

Tags: python, circular-dependency

In my code, I have two classes in different modules that need each other for type hinting purposes. Since this is a circular import issue, I have used `from __future__ import annotations` in the top of each of my modules' file, but that has not fixed my issue. I still get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\bil\Aircraft.py", line 10, in <module>
    from bil.Crew import Seat
  File "C:\...\bil\Crew.py", line 9, in <module>
    from bil.Aircraft import Aircraft
  File "C:\...\bil\Aircraft.py", line 10, in <module>
    from bil.Crew import Seat
ImportError: cannot import name 'Seat' from 'bil.Crew' (C:\...\bil\Crew.py)
```

Samples of my code:
Aircraft.py:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from bil.Crew import Seat

@dataclass
class Aircraft:
    ...
    defaultCrewComposition: OrderedDict[Seat, int]
    ...
```

Crew.py

```
from __future__ import annotations
from bil.Aircraft import Aircraft

@dataclass
class Seat:
    ... (nothing linked to Aircraft)

@dataclass
class Category:
    ...
    aircraft: Aircraft
```

As a last resort I have added `from __future__ import annotations` to every single project files but yet I still get that error. If I remove that specific circular dependency, others crop up. 
My version of python is 3.7.6.
Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong and how I could fix it?

Comment: Imports aren't annotations. If `Aircraft` isn't used anywhere *except* an annotation, you don't need to import it.

Comment: If you *do* have a circular depdendency between `Aircraft.py` and `Crew.py`, that's something you need to resolve independently of type hinting.

Comment: `from typing import TYPE_CHECKING` then later in your code for the import: `if TYPE_CHECKING:` and put the import in that if condition.  It should then resolve.